# Debugging with gdb in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb

I debug my own program in Eclipse and gdb tells me this on the launch:

```
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Try to install the hash file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/cb/f50fd61d2a433e6fbe1425843f8e49ea6c1ea0.debug
```

What should I do with it?

Comment: You should still be able to debug. Or install what it says (ld-linux debug info; I don't know how to do that on your distro), and it will stop complaining.

Comment: It's Altlinux 7.0 Centaurus